# PayPal and item_name

Tags: paypal

Can I see what was entered in the item_name field (by the customer) in my PayPal account? I know that I can see it if I use IPN but I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you go to **History** under **My Account** for a business acount, you can view the list of transactions sorted and filter by date ranges. From here if you select **details** for a rowitem/transaction you can see the values of most of the parameters sent with the transaction, including item_name. Even though I think on the transaction datails page its shown as **Item Title**.